# How can I create an node using Inheritance and the Sprite Kit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I try to create multiple nodes when loading a level. For this I use the following code in **GameScene.swift**:

```
func createUnits() {

    let myUnit = Unit()
    myUnit.attack()
}
```

The **Unit class** is still kept very simple:

```
class Unit: GameScene {

    var livePoints = 10
    var damage = 5
    var movement = 1

    func attack() {
        print("Attack!!")
    }
}
```

When compiling, I get the following error at `let myUnit = Unit()`:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee771cff8)
```

Does anyone have an idea, how to create a node without get this error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You probably want to subclass a `SKNode` instead of a `GameScene`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have replaced `GameScene` with `SkNode` and it works.

Comment: I am going to go out on a limb here and say something in your GameScene class is causing the crash.  Even though you used the wrong class for Units, you may want to look into why your GameScene is crashing on init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like its not a Node, but a Scene.
the first line in your Unit class shows you are subclassing GameScene instead of a SKNode